# Triangulo vazado com css

Tags: css, css3

Estou precisando fazer este tipo de efeito com css será que tem como ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não teria importância utilizar `css3` nem nenhum tecnologia, este tipo de `css` será usado em um aplicativo feito em `ionic`, não sei se isto importaria algo.

Preciso a reprodução identica a este, contendo um ícone e um texto dentro.

Tentei utilizar `border-radius` e `rotate` porem ele rodou todo conteúdo da `div`.

```
.triangle {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transform: rotate(50deg);
}


<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <div class="triangle">
      <ion-icon name="md-book" class=""></ion-icon>
     <span>Algum texto</span>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: Já cogitou aplicar `border-radius` e `transform: rotate()` em uma `div`?

Comment: não, como ficaria ?

Comment: Até tentei aqui porém ele virou o conteúdo da div juntamente.

Comment: Dá para fazer com `rotate:(-50deg)` no `span` e com posicionamento `absoluto` no `span` e relativo no `.triangle`. E para ficar inclinado no angulo certo seriam `45deg`

Comment: @Isac poderia cria uma resposta para dar o exemplo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma solução é criar um *pseudo-elemento* e fazer a rotação nele, assim o elemento em sí não irá girar também:

```css
html, body{ background: #000; color: #fff; }

.triangle {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    display: flex;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    flex-direction:column;
}
.triangle::before{
    display:block;
    content: "";
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 10px; /* altere este valor para controlar a curvatura das pontas */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <div class="triangle">
      <ion-icon name="md-book" class=""></ion-icon>
         <span>Algum texto</span>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma de fazer o que pretende é aplicar a rotação inversa no elemento filho (o `<span>`), e colocar o seu posicionamento como absoluto, e o do pai como relativo.

Segue exemplo:

```css
.triangle {
  margin:50px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border:2px solid orange;
  transform: rotate(45deg); /*45 para ter a inclinação certa*/
  position:relative; /*<---*/
}

.triangle span { 
  position:absolute; /*<---*/
  transform: rotate(-45deg); /*<---*/
}
```

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-4>
    <div class="triangle">
      <ion-icon name="md-book" class=""></ion-icon>
      <span>Algum texto</span>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Alterei ligeiramente outros estilos para ser mais fácil de ver e ficar também mais perto da figura que tem na pergunta.